# Using Functional Programming to compute prime numbers efficiently

Tags: performance, f#, functional-programming

I'm getting acquainted with F# by going over Project Euler and solving some of the problems. Many of the early problems consist of prime numbers. After looking around I came up with the following solution:

```
let primesL =
    let rec prim n sofar = 
        seq { if (sofar |> List.forall (fun i->n%i <>0L)) then
                  yield n
                  yield! prim (n+1L) (n::sofar)
              else
                  yield! prim (n+1L) sofar  }
    prim 2L []
```

This works well, but then I generate all the prime numbers up to 2000000:

```
let smallPrimes = primesL |> Seq.takeWhile (fun n->n<=2000000)
```

This takes *ages*. It's quite obvious something is done in O(N^2) or worst.

I know I can write an imperative version and implement a [sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) of some sort, but I want to stick to functional code. If I wanted imperative, I would have stayed with C#.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing _encapsulation_. Write a sieve, and give it a functional _interface_ -- no one needs to know the implementation details.

Comment: I should have been clear about the purpose of learning F# - I'm considering it for *some* parts of a big project. The other parts will be C#. If I need to resort to imperative code for most of the calculations, I'll just keep everything in C#.

Comment: you can implement Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm using purely functional approach, [here's one in Haskell](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Basic_list-based_sieve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to compare your approach with [my variant of Problem Euler 10 solution](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/project-euler-problem-10/)

```
let rec primes = 
    Seq.cache <| seq { yield 2; yield! Seq.unfold nextPrime 3 }
and nextPrime n =
    if isPrime n then Some(n, n + 2) else nextPrime(n + 2)
and isPrime n =
    if n >= 2 then
        primes 
        |> Seq.tryFind (fun x -> n % x = 0 || x * x > n)
        |> fun x -> x.Value * x.Value > n
    else false
```

It is purely functional, uses sequence cashing, optimized for primality check; also it yields very useful `isPrime n` function as a co-result.

And being applied to the original problem

```
let problem010 () =
    primes
    |> Seq.takeWhile ((>) 2000000)
    |> (Seq.map int64 >> Seq.sum)
```

it completes in **decent 2.5 s**. This is not blasting fast, but was good enough to use this `primes` sequence in handful of [my other Project Euler solutions](http://infsharpmajor.wordpress.com) (27, 35, 37, 50, 58, 69, 70, 77 so far).

As to what you're missing in your solution - from your code I believe you're building a brand new sequence on each internal call to `prim`, i.e. for each natural while my approach uses a **single** sequence for already found primes and only **enumerates** its cached instance when producing each next prime.

Comment: This seems both quick *and* concise. I'll give it a try, I just have to make sure I understand this first.

Comment: @zmbq: It may help you to look at a [great post](http://diditwith.net/2008/09/17/YAPESProblemSevenPart1.aspx) by Dustin Campbell
on the subject; he came up with pretty similar approach much ahead of me )c:

Comment: Cool. It has one optimization you didn't use - instead of using n+2 in nextPrime, I used
`let inline next n = if n%6=1 then n+4 else n+2`
It saved another 10% of the execution time.

Comment: The trick here is that when isPrime is called for a candidate C, it checks primes up to sqrt(C), and all the primes up to C have already been saved in the cache? That's why it works fast?

Answer (score 8):

Rather than write a long answer here, I refer you to [Melissa O'Neill's great paper on the sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Comment: Also F# implementation of Melissa O'Neill's approach can be found in [another great post of Dustin Campbell](http://diditwith.net/2009/01/20/YAPESProblemSevenPart2.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First, it *is* `O(n^2)` - remember that you use `List.forall` on each iteration.

Second, if you use the generator a lot, you should cache the results (so that each prime number is only calculated once):

```
let primesL =
    let rec prim n sofar = 
        seq { if (sofar |> List.forall (fun i -> n % i <> 0UL)) then
                  yield n
                  yield! prim (n + 1UL) (n::sofar)
              else
                  yield! prim (n + 1UL) sofar }
    prim 2UL []
    |> Seq.cache
```

Comment: I do not think placing `Seq.cache` where you placed it may help to speedup things as the cause of slowness is in implementation of `prim`.

Comment: Seq.cache definitely didn't help prim, but it helps if someone ever uses primesL more than once.

Comment: I didn't say it would make the computation go faster, I only said it would help on second or later use.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want here is a sieve - I have written a pretty fast F# sieve before here:

[F# parallelizing issue when calculating perfect numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368107/f-parallelizing-issue-when-calculating-perfect-numbers/8371684#8371684)

Answer (score -1):

Use "[Miller–Rabin primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)" for more than some large prime number

Comment: This is not a good solution if you want to test the primality of a large amount of numbers - a sieve is faster

Comment: In large numbers, it is pulling his leg seems to be like List.forall so obvious,
Be replaced by high-speed determination that part, (enough to downvote?) so bad I did not think to...