# f# sum a List of Int32 throws Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to get the sum of all prime numbers from 0 to 2 000 000

this is my code:

```
let getPrimesUpTo (x : System.Int32) =
    let upperBound = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(x)))

    let allNumbers = ref [1..x] in    
    for div = 2 to upperBound do allNumbers := List.filter (fun num -> (num % div <> 0 || div >= num)) !allNumbers    
    allNumbers

let sop = 
    let nums = !(getPrimesUpTo 2000000)
    List.sum nums
```

when I run it I get: "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow"

If I don't do List.sum I get the list of primes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.sum` uses checked operators which throw on overflow.  You can chase this through the source

```
List.sum calls Seq.sum
Seq.sum calls Checked.(+)
```

`Checked.(+)` throws an error on overflow.  Side note: This is why `List.Fold (+)` is faster than `List.sum`

To fix this you would need to change your code to use 64 bit ints (which should be big enough), I also tidied up the conversion between double and int

```
let getPrimesUpTo (x : int64) =
    let upperBound = x |> float |>sqrt |> int64

    let allNumbers = ref [1L..x]    
    for div in 2L..upperBound do allNumbers := List.filter (fun num -> (num % div <> 0L || div >= num)) !allNumbers    
    allNumbers

let sop = 
    let nums = !(getPrimesUpTo 2000000L)
    List.sum nums
```

This method for calculating primes is very inefficient.  I have written some quite good code to calculate large numbers of primes in F# - see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371684/124259

Answer (score 3):

Presumably `List.sum` is going to try to sum the values to an `Int32` value... and presumably the sum of the primes up to 2,000,000 is greater than `Int32.MaxValue`. I suspect `Int64` would be okay though - so try just changing `Convert.ToInt32` to `Convert.ToInt64`.

Comment: and also, I get a List of Int32 numbers, the only problem is the List.Sum

Comment: @ChuckNorris: Without being familiar with F#, can you specify a transformation as part of the `List.sum` call? e.g. `List.sum nums Convert.ToInt64`

Comment: @JonSkeet - you could change to `List.sum (List.map int64 (!(getPrimesUpTo 2000000L))`