# F# vs C# performance for prime number generator

Tags: c#, performance, f#, primes

I have noticed that seemingly equivalent code in F# and C# do not perform the same. The F# is slower by the order of magnitude. As an example I am providing my code which generates prime numbers/gives nth prime number in F# and C#. My F# code is:

```
let rec isprime x =
primes
|> Seq.takeWhile (fun i -> i*i <= x)
|> Seq.forall (fun i -> x%i <> 0)

and primes = 
    seq {
        yield 2
        yield! (Seq.unfold (fun i -> Some(i, i+2)) 3)
                |> Seq.filter isprime
    }


let n = 1000
let start = System.DateTime.Now
printfn "%d" (primes |> Seq.nth n)
let duration = System.DateTime.Now - start
printfn "Elapsed Time: "
System.Console.WriteLine duration
```

And C# looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static bool isprime(int n)
    {
        foreach (int p in primes())
        {
            if (p * p > n)
                return true;
            if (n % p == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> primes()
    {
        yield return 2;
        for (int i=3; ; i+=2)
        {
            if (isprime(i))
                yield return i;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 1000;
        var pr = primes().GetEnumerator();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int count=0; count<n; count++)
        {
            pr.MoveNext();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(pr.Current);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine("Duration " + (end - start));
    }
}
```

When I measure for different `n` I get advantage for C# of at least 7x as follows:

- n=  100: C#=5milsec  F#=64milsec
- n= 1000: C#=22milsec  F#=180milsec
- n= 5000: C#=280milsec F#=2.05sec
- n=10000: C#=960milsec F#=6.95sec

My questions:

- Are these two programs equivalent?
- If yes, why aren't they compiled into a same/equivalent CLI?
- If not, why not?
- How can I/Can I improve my F# prime numbers generator to perform more similar to the C# one?
- Generally, can I (or why can I not) always mimic C# code in F# so my F# code would perform equally fast?

Edit1: I've realized that the algorithm itself can be improved by traversing only through odd and not prime numbers in isprime, making it non-recursive, but this is kind of perpendicular fact to the questions asked :)

Comment: One obvious difference is that takewhile and then forall might potentially involve two passes over the data which could be catastrophic particularly if the sequence doesn't get cached.

Comment: That's a really good catch! I thought the compiler would optimize it away, but on the second thought I see it wouldn't. Then what is a good way of combining Seq.takeWhile and Seq.forall?

Comment: If you want to go crazy, try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014224/when-generating-primes-in-f-why-is-the-sieve-of-erosthenes-so-slow-in-this-p/12014908#12014908

Comment: Also, don't use Datetime, use stopwatch

Comment: @JohnPalmer - I'm curious what you mean about "two passes" - `primes` will only be iterated once per call to `isprime` (as can be seen by adding some `printf`s).

Comment: Seq's are known to be slow. If you want to benchmark, try to avoid them. I had some parser using seq's once and it was too slow to be useful. Left to state, that it is not actually the seq's per-se, but rather the idiomatic way of using them which produces slow code. ``Seq.take 1 ...`` produces a new sequence (immutability!). <<--- overhead.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This:

> Are these two programs equivalent?

is a bit of a philosophical question.

It looks to me like the output of the C# and F# implementations of `isprime` will always agree for any given `x`, so in that sense they're equivalent.  However, there are many differences in terms of how you've implemented them (e.g. `Seq.unfold` will create an intermediate `IEnumerable<_>` value, then `Seq.filter` will create another one, so you're generating a lot more short-lived objects and using a lot more function calls in the F# code), so it's not at all surprising that they're not equivalent in terms of the low-level instructions that are generated by the respective compilers.

If you want to, you can create F# code that's much more similar to the C# code, at the expense of being much more imperative and less idiomatic:

```
let rec primes = 
    seq {
        yield 2
        let mutable x = 3
        while true do
            if isprime x then 
                yield x
            x <- x + 2
    }
and isprime x =
    use e = primes.GetEnumerator()
    let rec loop() =
        if e.MoveNext() then
            let p = e.Current
            if p * p > x then true
            elif x % p = 0 then false
            else loop()
        else true            
    loop()
```

`primes |> Seq.item 5000` takes about 0.6s on my machine with this implementation, compared to about 2.7s with your implementation.  I think in general the code generation for F# `seq` expressions is often slightly worse than that of C# iterators, so I wouldn't be surprised if the C# is still somewhat quicker to run.  (But also note that some idioms end up being faster in F# than in C#, so it's not the case that F# is always slower - in my experience the two languages are pretty comparable overall, and I find writing F# code much more enjoyable).

In any case, rather than sweating the details of how to make the F# compiler's output more closely match the C# compiler's, I'd recommend looking for algorithmic improvements instead.  For example, simply placing a call to `Seq.cache` at the end of your original definition of `primes` makes `primes |> Seq.item 5000` take only 0.062 seconds on my machine, which is dramatically faster than the original C#.